# How to encapsulate Exceptions from handlers?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, vert.x

I'm working on an application that has different layers(Handlers -> Services -> DAO).

```
EmployeeHandler {
    Employee get(){...}
    Employee save(){...}
    Employee update(){...}
    etc(){...}
}

CompanyHandler {
    Company get(){...}
    Company save(){...}
    Company update(){...}
    etc(){...}
}

ManagerHandler {
   Manager get(){...}
   Manager save(){...}
   Manager update(){...}
   etc(){...}
}
```

The handlers are the ones catching the exceptions. They have the same methods but with different implementation, I perform some validations and more required tasks.

```
Manager save(){
  try{
    // do something
    employeeService.save(employee);
   } 
   catch (MyCustomException e) {
     // handle exception -- here I do the same for each method in all handlers
   } 
   catch (Exception e) {
     // catch any exception -- here I also do the same thing for all handlers
    }
}
```

So basically the only code that changes is the one inside the 'try' block, the rest is the same in every handler.

I want to encapsulate the exception handling so I don't have to repeat everywhere, and in the future If I have to deal with any exception different I don't have to make the change in all handlers.

The idea I have is since I'm using Spring, I could create a bean 'ExceptionHandler' so it can be inject in all handlers, but I would like to know if there are better ways to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick example I wrote which doesn't use anything from Spring (I am sure Spring must be providing you with something for the above scenario)

```
interface ExceptionHandler<T extends Throwable> {

    void handle(T exception);

}

class UnsupportedOperationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<UnsupportedOperationException> {

    @Override
    public void handle(UnsupportedOperationException exception) {
        //blaa
    }
}

class IllegalArguementExceptionHandler implements ExceptionHandler<IllegalArgumentException> {

    @Override
    public void handle(IllegalArgumentException exception) {
        //blaa part 2
    }
}

class YourHandler {

    private final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, ExceptionHandler> exceptionHandlers; //This will contain all your handlers

    @Inject
    YourHandler(Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, ExceptionHandler> exceptionHandlers) {
        this.exceptionHandlers = exceptionHandlers;
    }

    public void save() {
        try {
            //some method here.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exceptionHandlers.get(e.getClass()).handle(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Spring provides a `@ExceptionHandler` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) to handle in a handler method specific exceptions risen by methods from a class .
Just annotate the methods that will be the exception handler and specifies the expected exception class to handle in each one.

For example :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
public void handleException(MyCustomException e) {
     ... // exception handling

}

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public void handleException(Exception e) {
     ... // exception handling        
}
```

If your handlers are Spring beans, you could create an abstract class that will contains the handler methods for the exception handling and then you can make your concrete handlers inherited from it.

---

If your handlers are Spring controllers and you want to do the exception handling in the same way for all controllers, you could make things still simpler by declaring a bean with the [`@ControllerAdvice` annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) and by specifying the generic way to handle the exception in.
You don't need any longer to have a common abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Spring AOP's `@AfterThrowing` advice (shown below) to handle the exceptions at a central place (you can look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-advice-after-throwing) for Spring doc example):

```
@Aspect
public class MyProjectExceptionHandler {

    @AfterThrowing (pointcut = "execution(* com.myproject.service.impl..*(..))", 
                              throwing = "ex")
    public void handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException ex) 
                       throws Throwable  { 
         //add your code here
        }

    @AfterThrowing (pointcut = "execution(* com.myproject.service.impl..*(..))", 
                   throwing = "ex")
    public void handleException(Exception ex) 
       throws Throwable  {
       //add your code here
      }
}
```